# Multiple plugins in cxxfunction

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to use RcppGSL and RcppArmadillo at the same time, is that possible to use multiple plugins in cxxfunction (of the inline CRAN package) ?
I found a way to do:

```
plug.ArmaGSL <- Rcpp:::Rcpp.plugin.maker(include.before='#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
                                                     #include <RcppGSL.h>
                                                     #include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>',
                                     Depends=c("RcppGSL", "RcppArmadillo", "Rcpp"),
                                     LinkingTo=c("RcppGSL", "RcppArmadillo", "Rcpp"),
                                     libs="-lgsl -larmadillo")

registerPlugin("RcppArmaGSL", plug.ArmaGSL)

foo <- cxxfunction(signature(sM="numeric"), body=bodytxt, inc=inctxt, plugin="RcppArmaGSL")
```

but it seems not that intuitive.

Comment: Your edit is fine. That's how you define and register a plugin for `cxxfunction()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question. (And would have been even better on rcpp-devel.)

I think you need to write your own combined plugin, see Question 3.6 'How do I write a plugin for the inline package' of the Rcpp-FAQ vignette for details.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to start from an existing plugin, say:

```
require(inline)
require(RcppArmadillo)
foo <- getPlugin("RcppArmadillo" )
```

and then mess with foo, and use it as the settings argument in the cxxfunction call. More on that in ?cxxfunction.

Comment: Yep. But I also like what we say in the Rcpp-FAQ.

Comment: sure thing. two different angles :-)