# RcppArmadillo and RcppGSL

Tags: rcpp

I would like to utilize both RcppArmadillo and RcppGSL via sourceCpp. Basically I am interested in modifying the B-spline example

http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2012/12/08/

so that the B-splines are functions of R^3 instead of only R^1. This entails working with 3-dimensional arrays which apparently is not supported in GSL (there is an extension here http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/marray though). However, RcppArmadillo has the arma::cube type which I could use if only I could get RcppArmadillo and RcppGSL to "work together."  This I am unfortunately not able to do. I have looked at

[Multiple plugins in cxxfunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978636/multiple-plugins-in-cxxfunction)

but have not succeeded in creating the mentioned combined plugin. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Adam

Edit: It seems like it is actually possible to compile a .cpp file with sourceCpp containing the following sequence of commands at the top:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppGSL.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_bspline.h>
```

Furthermore, it also seems possible to store values like

double gsl_vector_get (const gsl_vector * v, size_t i)

in an arma::cube structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RcppArmadillo.h` and `RcppGSL.h` are modelled similarly. They first include `RcppCommon.h`, then some forward declarations, then they include `Rcpp.h` that uses those forward declarations, then implementations.

It is definitely possible to use them both if you come up with the right order of includes.

This is definitely an Rcpp question as what is preventing you from using them both is (good or bad) design decisions.

You need to study `RcppArmadillo.h` and `RcppGSL.h` and come up with the right include order, or wait for someone to follow these hints and give you the answer. I might not have time to do it myself in the next few days.

Comment: I will try and have a look at the .h files. Thanks!

Comment: RcppArmadillo and RcppGSL are mechanisms to communicate and exchange data to and from R. But here the OP wants to connect Armadillo and GSL directly ("can I stick Arma::cube into GSL to get a R^3 spline?") which one cannot do even if both libraries can connect to R via our tools.

Comment: Well, actually I would like to use RcppGSL to evaluate three sets of B-spline functions on three subsets of R^1 and then store these values in an arma::cube.  This is possible already

Comment: Yes. But you can't directly assign (Rcpp)GSL vectors in Armadillo, but you could either go via R (and Rcpp) data structures, or go via intermediate representation suck as `std::vector<double>`, or, if you must, a `double*`.

Comment: I can evaluate the three sets of B-spline functions on three subsets of R^1. For each datapoint and each B-spline I get a value. This value I would like to store in a matrix (not necessarily an arma::mat). This gives me three matrices. The values in these matrices should then be combined (in connection with a simulation procedure) and the resulting values are then to be stored in an array - an arma::cube. As in the B-spline example if I do 
double Bj = gsl_vector_get(B, j); 
is Bj then a "regular" double that could be stored in say an arma::mat?

Comment: Sure, once you are down to atomistic double types you are fine. But vectors etc don't mix directly.

Answer (score 0):

Armadillo types and GSL types are not interchangeable.

You could rewrite the GSL algorithm for Armadillo, but it is not automatic but any means. I am also not sure if the theory behind splines extends just like that from the real line to three-dimensions.

Comment: Ok. But is it not possible to write a c++ program (i.e. without R hence Rcpp involved) using both the GSL and the Armadillo library? What I had in mind was simply to implement so called tensor B-splines. These can be obtained essentially as a linear combination of one-dimensional B-splines.

Comment: True! Since the tensor splines computations are "loopy" it would have been nice to be able to make the these with c++ speed and then transfer the data to R.

Comment: I am just saying that you now have a generic C++ (or modeling) problem so you may want to alter the tag it is under...  Getting that C++ solution into R is then easy thanks to Rcpp.